# How can I remove Windows from this business network?

Tags: windows-xp, home-networking

I bought a machine from a friend that used to be on a network.  He gave me his user name and password, however the network/business no longer exists so I can't log back in to fix current problems.

I need to set up the machine for a home network.  Windows won't let me set this up for home networking.  Any ideas?

I don't want to reinstall WinXP Pro and lose programs.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the machine is joined to a domain. Change the logon type to local (under "Log on to:" choose "Hostname (this computer)" and log on using the local administrator account.

If you do not know the local administrator account you will need to get a Windows XP password reset CD and run that.

Once you are into the computer as a local administrator you can "join" the computer back to a workgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Further for taspeotis' answer the way to do that is:

1. Reset the password
2. "System" con trol panel -> network -> "network ID", switch to using a workgroup
3. Reboot
4. Now join to the domain

Comment: He doesn't want it back on the domain, just to the workgroup.